# MPAndroidChart XAxis lables

Tags: mpandroidchart

I have a c# chart that looks like the image.  I need to make something similar in MPAndroidChart 3.1.0.  But I cannot figure out how to set the xaxis tick marks (0,600,1200...) and label ( Energy(KeV) ) .

[image]

[image]

Closer but I still can't figure out how to get the lables across the bottom of the xaxis.

[image]

```
 XAxis xAxis                 = chart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines        (true);
    xAxis.enableGridDashedLine    (10f, 10f, 0f);
    xAxis.setPosition             (XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    //xAxis.setAxisMinimum           (0f);
    //xAxis.setAxisMaximum           (3000f); //this works but the line doesn't draw all the way across
    //xAxis.setLabelCount            (10);
    // xAxis.setDrawLabels           (true);
    xAxis.setTextColor            (Color.WHITE);
    xAxis.setTextSize             (12f);
```

I got it. Seems all you really had to do was setPosition, color and size